# How to write a regular expressions to populate a list with given file types & exclude certain folders

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I've done a lot of searching on this but still can't quite put it all together.

I'm trying create an Excel VBA program that populates a spreadsheet based on a user inputting regular expressions so that I can process the files with other vba programs.

So for example, if I want to populate a folder with all Autodesk Inventor file types , I would use:

```
.*\.(iam|ipt|ipn|idw)
```

and from what I have read, if I want a regex to skip a file in a folder OR containing a string, I would use something like:

```
(?iOldVersions)
```

but like I mentioned, I am having trouble putting this together so that it is a single reg ex call -- and also, if there are multiple strings that I want it to skip (ie; the folders *OldVersions* and *Legacy*)

I think I would like to keep it as regex although I'm guessing I could also use wScript.Shell (or whatever that object is) but It would be nice to just get familiar with regular expressions for now.

The code I am using is the same from this post, but instead I added a parameter to pass the pattern to the top level code by pulling it from a cell in excel.

[List files of certain pattern using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555776/list-files-of-certain-pattern-using-excel-vba)

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks again, all!

Edit: Latest attempt....

```
Private Sub FindPatternMatchedFiles()

objFile = "C:\OldVersions\TestFile.iam"

Dim objRegExp As Object
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

'objRegExp.Pattern = "(.*\.(iam|ipt|ipn|idw))(?!(\z))."
objRegExp.Pattern = "(^((?!OldVersions).)*$)(.*\.(iam|ipt|ipn|idw))"

objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

res = objRegExp.test(objFile)
MsgBox (res)

'Garbage Collection
Set objRegExp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: So after about 2 hrs of searching, I came across a post that suggested I need to use look-aheads to reset the expressions (this literally is another language to me). This results in:

"(?=(^((?!OldVersions).)*$))(.*\.(iam|ipt|ipn|idw))"

which seems to work.

Source:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869809/combine-regexp

Comment: Don't use the tempered greedy token here, a mere lookahead will do.

Answer (score 2):

To exclude matching strings having `\OldVersions\` or `\Legacy\`, just add anchors and a negative lookahead at the start:

```
^(?!.*\\(?:OldVersions|Legacy)\\).*\.(?:iam|ipt|ipn|idw)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nB9hE0/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\\(?:OldVersions|Legacy)\\)` - a negative lookahead failing the match if there is `\` + either `OldVersions` or `Legacy` + `\` after 0+ chars other than `\r` and `\n` (`.*`).
- `.*` - 0+ chars other than `\r` and `\n`, as many as possible, up to the last...
- `\.` - literal `.`
- `(?:iam|ipt|ipn|idw)` - one of the alternatives in the non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.